# How to remove Content-Length from header on WSO2 sequence?

Tags: wso2, chunking

I need to disable chunking for my request.

I added `<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>` on my sequence. This removed Transfer-Encoding from header but Content-Length is still in header.

How do i remove Content-Length from header in WSO2 sequence.

Answer (score 0):

When chunking is disabled the content-length header will remain. It is an expected phenomena in http. To disable chunking use the following properties in your proxy:

```
<property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2" />
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" />
```

For more information refer:

http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2016/12/disable-chunking-in-wso2-api-manager.html

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>`, the request will be chuncked and `Content-Lnegth` header will be removed.